# HTML: Fill available width

Tags: html, css

What I'm trying to do is this:

[image]

In text form:

```
XXX Some text here YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY ZZZZZZZZZ

Body body body                                          Sidebar!
Body body body                                          Sidebar!
Body body body                                          Sidebar!
```

X, Y, and Z are images (3 images total). Y can stretch along the X axis, and does so above, to fill the available space. (But doesn't cause "Some text here" to get squished and start breaking into multiple lines)

I'd like to keep the "Some text here" part in one line. A line breaking here will not end happily.

Is this possible, or should I simplify the layout around HTML?

---

My current attempt using tables:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" border="0" style="height: 20px; width: 100%;">
  <tr>
    <td style="width: 205px; height: 20px; background: url('images/horz_bar_left_end.png');">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 5px; height: 20px; background: url('images/transparent.gif');"/>&nbsp;</td>
    <td valign="center" style="height: 20px; white-space: nowrap; font-weight: bold;">THIS IS A TITLE</td>
    <td style="width: 5px; height: 20px; background: url('images/transparent.gif');">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 100%; background: url('images/blue.gif');">&nbsp;</td>
    <td style="width: 190px; height: 20px; background: url('images/horz_bar_right_upper.png');">&nbsp;</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Close... ish. *All* of the columns (except the one with the text, and the `width: 100%` one) are ignoring their CSS width attribute in both Firefox and Chrome. This is what it looks like:

[image]

My attempt using `<div>` and all that CSS jazz.

```
<div style="white-space: nowrap;">
  <div style="float:left; width: 25px; height: 20px; background: url('images/horz_bar_left_end2.png');">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="float:left;">Some Text</div>
  <div style="float:left; width: 100%; height: 20px; background: url('images/blue.gif') repeat;">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="float:left; width: 190px; height: 20px; background: url('images/horz_bar_right_upper.png');">&nbsp;</div>
  <div style="clear: both;"></div>
  <div style="float:left; width: 500px;"> body </div>
  <div style="float:left; width: 100px;"> sidebar </div>
</div>
```

...massively fails. It's on like three lines.

For those wanting to play at home, here are the images:

- horz_bar_left_end.png: [image]
- horz_bar_right_upper.png [image]
- transparent.gif: 1x1 transparent GIF
- blue.png: 1x1 blue PNG. (#0073e4)

Comment: huhh? clarify a bit more

Comment: @andrewk: Which part is unclear?

Comment: @Babiker: `display:inline` what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do with many way to archive your web layout.

[image]

Code update and look at http://jsbin.com/awudi4/

Comment: Not quite: The blue bar should stop (break to black) for the text. (Text is white on black) She the image of the table above, it gets that much. (Additionally, your HTML is missing a `</div>` somewhere.)

Comment: You can drop both `display: block`, the `float` and the `width`.

Comment: It took me a minute to understand how this was working. This is fairly close: I was hoping to have the black area be transparent, and let it use the background, same with the curved edges. Otherwise, this is by far the closest, so I'm +1-ing it at the very least.

Answer (score 2):

LOL! Let's see if I understand... Try this!

HTML:

```
<div id="foo">
    <h3>This is my CSS title! :)</h3>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#foo {
    width:900px;
    margin:0 auto; /* center to the screen horizontally */
    background:#ccc;

    /* increase border radius until it is curvefull! */
    border-radius:25px;
    -moz-border-radius:25px;
    -webkit-border-radius:25px;
}
#foo h3 {
    font:bold 14px Georgia, Arial, Sans;
    color:#333;
    margin:0;
    padding:25px 0 25px 50px; /* top, right, bottom, left */
}
```

Simpler? XD

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<table><tr>
  <td>XXX</td>
  <td>Some text here</td>
  <td>YYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYYY</td>
  <td>ZZZZZZZZZ</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: This is what I currently have, and have yet to get working. Replace the Y's with an image: what do you set for the horizontal width?

Comment: Is Y one big image, or does every Y represent one image?

Comment: Y is one large image, stretchable along the X axis, to fill the available width.

Comment: This doesn't really justify using a table, -1.

Comment: @Ege Özcan: Except tables have provided the closest answer so far. I've yet to see anything CSS that even remotely approximates the desired effect.

Comment: @Thanatos: HTML is first about semantics, not looks. Tables are for tabular information. I'm sure what you are trying to do can be done via proper CSS and if I could really understand your question I'd definitely try to help but no luck so far. Sorry.

Comment: @Ege Özcan: I recently attached an image to the top of the question: hopefully it'll clarify the question for you.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div style="float:left; width: 100px; background: url(X) repeat-x;"> </div>
<div style="float:left;"> Some Text </div>
<div style="float:left; width: 200px; background: url(Y) repeat-x;"> </div>
<div style="float:left; width: 150px; background: url(Z) repeat-x;"> </div>
<div style="clear: both;"></div>
<div style="float:left; width: 500px;"> body </div>
<div style="float:left; width: 100px;"> sidebar </div>
```

You can change widths for your wrapper width

Comment: I'm trying this, but this doesn't seem to answer the core of the question: How do I get the Y part to stretch? (Without manually settings a width.) Also, this isn't valid HTML. (I've also fixed the SO formatting.)

Comment: Sorry. After all style there must be a "=". style="float: left;"

Comment: And all divs height must be equivalent imgs height. Then add height property